# How can I remove nan columns if values are string/Integer dtypes at once?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like:

```
In [1]: d = {'ID': [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15], 
         'NAME': ['KWI', 'NED', 'RICK', 'NICH', 'DIONIC', 'RICHARD', 'ROCKY', 'CARLOS', 'SIDARTH'], 
         'ID_COUNTRY':[1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
         'COUNTRY':['MEXICO', 'ITALY', 'CANADA', 'ENGLAND', 'GERMANY', 'UNITED STATES', 'JAPAN', 'SPAIN', 'BRAZIL'], 
         'ID_CITY':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
         'CITY':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
         'STATUS': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Out[2]:
      ID       NAME      ID_COUNTRY     COUNTRY        ID_CITY     CITY     STATUS
0     14       KWI           1           MEXICO          NaN        NaN        OK
1     14       NED           2           ITALY           NaN        NaN        OK
2     14       RICK          3           CANADA          NaN        NaN        OK
3     14       NICH          4           ENGLAND         NaN        NaN       OK
4     14       DIONIC        5           GERMANY         NaN        NaN        OK 
5     14       RICHARD       6           UNITED STATES   NaN        NaN        NOT
6     14       ROCKY         7           JAPAN           NaN        NaN        OK
7     15       CARLOS        8           SPAIN           NaN        NaN        NOT
8     15       SIDHART       9           BRAZIL          NaN        NaN        OK
```

Then I need to set the dtypes of each column for future uses using:

```
df.iloc[:, [0, 2, 4]] = df.iloc[:, [0, 2, 4]].astype("Int64")
df.iloc[:, [1, 3, 5, 6]] = df.iloc[:, [1, 3, 5, 6]].astype("string")
```

After doing this I want to drop the columns that have completely `nan` values and get the names of the columns dropped to be remmoved in another dataframe with the same column names like this:

```
 In [3]: d1 = {'ID': [14, 14, 14], 
         'NAME': ['KWI', 'NED', 'RICK'], 
         'ID_COUNTRY':[1, 2, 3], 
         'COUNTRY':['MEXICO', 'ITALY', 'CANADA'], 
         'ID_CITY':[20, 22, 24], 
         'CITY':['MX', 'AT', 'CA'], 
         'STATUS': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK']}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
 Out [4]: 
      ID       NAME      ID_COUNTRY     COUNTRY        ID_CITY     CITY     STATUS
0     14       KWI           1           MEXICO          20        MX        OK
1     14       NED           2           ITALY           22        AT        OK
2     14       RICK          3           CANADA          24        CA        OK
```

The issue here is when I try `df['CITY'].isna()` because is giving me `False` for all the values in the column. I do not why is giving me that and when I try with `df['ID_CITY'].isna()` is giving me `True`. I guess is because one is `Int64` and the other `object`.
Examples:

```
In [5]: df4['ID_CITY'].isna()                       
Out[6]:                         
0    True                   
1    True
2    True                          
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
Name: ID_CITY, dtype: bool

In [7]: df4['CITY'].isna()
Out[8]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: CITY, dtype: bool
```

After correcting what I mention before the desired output for `df` and `df1` will be:

```
Out[9]:
      ID       NAME      ID_COUNTRY     COUNTRY          STATUS
0     14       KWI           1           MEXICO            OK
1     14       NED           2           ITALY             OK
2     14       RICK          3           CANADA            OK
3     14       NICH          4           ENGLAND           OK
4     14       DIONIC        5           GERMANY           OK 
5     14       RICHARD       6           UNITED STATES     NOT
6     14       ROCKY         7           JAPAN             OK
7     15       CARLOS        8           SPAIN             NOT
8     15       SIDHART       9           BRAZIL            OK

 Out [10]: 
      ID       NAME      ID_COUNTRY     COUNTRY     STATUS
0     14       KWI           1           MEXICO       OK
1     14       NED           2           ITALY        OK
2     14       RICK          3           CANADA       OK
```

Thaks for reading me.

Comment: The mistake you make is using `str`. You need: `df.iloc[:, [1, 3, 5, 6]] = df.iloc[:, [1, 3, 5, 6]].astype("object")`

Comment: I know it could be done in the way you say and also `astype("string")`. but how can I solve the main issue here? @Erfan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is (Instead of using column index, I have just used column names for clarifications):

```
d = {'ID': [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15], 
         'NAME': ['KWI', 'NED', 'RICK', 'NICH', 'DIONIC', 'RICHARD', 'ROCKY', 'CARLOS', 'SIDARTH'], 
         'ID_COUNTRY':[1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
         'COUNTRY':['MEXICO', 'ITALY', 'CANADA', 'ENGLAND', 'GERMANY', 'UNITED STATES', 'JAPAN', 'SPAIN', 'BRAZIL'], 
         'ID_CITY':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
         'CITY':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
         'STATUS': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

You can cast a pd object to a specified `dtype`. For that, you can use `Int64` and `str` (instead of string in your code) [[see the link]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

```
df[['ID', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'ID_CITY']] = df[['ID', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'ID_CITY']].astype("Int64")
df[['NAME', 'COUNTRY', 'CITY', 'STATUS']] = df[['NAME', 'COUNTRY', 'CITY', 'STATUS']].astype("str")
```

With a temporary typecasting, you can determine NaN values. For this, take into account that float accepts the strings `nan` with an optional prefix `+` or `-` for Not a Number (NaN).

```
df['CITY'].astype("float").isna()
```

The output:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
Name: CITY, dtype: bool
```

Either

```
df['ID_CITY'].isna()
```

or

```
df['ID_CITY'].astype("float").isna()
```

will result:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
Name: ID_CITY, dtype: bool
```